# Expected value of (F(x)/x(1-F(x)) where F(x) is CDF?

Tags: probability, expected-value, moments, hazard, bounds

I was solving a problem and encountered the following:

\sum (f(x)/x) (F(x)/(1-F(x))

Here f(x) is pmf and F(x) is CDF. Is expected value of F(x)/x(1-F(x)) a known function? I found out that f(x)/(1-F(x)) is called hazard function. Also, x is defined over positive values. It can be assumed that x is bounded between two values Xmin and Xmax.

I want to know more about characteristics of this expected value, is it bounded if we take sum until F(x) < 1?

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand this better.

Comment: Math formatting is implemented with Mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Cross post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2774534/321264.